# clever any() like function to check if at least n elements are True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

Say I have an iterable (in my case a list):

```
l = [True, False, False, True]
```

I know that the easiest and fastest way to check if at least one of those elements is True is simply to use `any(l)`, which will return `True`.

But what if I want to check that at least two elements are `True`?
My goal is to process it in the fastest way possible.

My code right now looks like this (for two elements):

```
def check_filter(l):
    if len([i for i in filter(None, l)]) > 1:
        return True
return False
```

This is about 10 times slower than `any()`, and does not seem very pythonic to me.

Comment: `sum(l) >= 2`  Not sure how "pythonic" it is, but it works.  Also, you don't need `filter()` in your example, try: `len([i for i in l if i]) >= 2`.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351219/efficiently-check-if-an-element-occurs-at-least-n-times-in-a-list

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could simply use an iterator over the sequence and check that `any` on the iterator returns always True for `n`-times:

```
def check(it, num):
    it = iter(it)
    return all(any(it) for _ in range(num))

>>> check([1, 1, 0], 2)
True

>>> check([1, 1, 0], 3)
False
```

The key point here is that an iterator remembers the position it was last so each `any` call will start where the last one ended. And wrapping it in `all` makes sure it exits early as soon as one `any` is `False`.

At least performance-wise this should be faster than most other approaches. However at the cost of readability.

---

If you want to have it even faster than a solution based on `map` and `itertools.repeat` can be slightly faster:

```
from itertools import repeat

def check_map(it, num):
    return all(map(any, repeat(iter(it), num)))
```

---

Benchmarked against the other answers:

```
# Second "True" element is in the last place
lst = [1] + [0]*1000 + [1]

%timeit check_map(lst, 2)  # 10000 loops, best of 3: 20.3 µs per loop
%timeit check(lst, 2)      # 10000 loops, best of 3: 23.5 µs per loop
%timeit many(lst, 2)       # 10000 loops, best of 3: 153 µs per loop
%timeit sum(l) >= 2        # 100000 loops, best of 3: 19.6 µs per loop

# Second "True" element is the second item in the iterable
lst = [1, 1] + [0]*1000

%timeit check_map(lst, 2)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 µs per loop
%timeit check(lst, 2)      # 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.39 µs per loop
%timeit many(lst, 2)       # 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.02 µs per loop
%timeit sum(lst) >= 2      # 10000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Or `return all(map(any, [iter(it)] * num))`, though it takes extra space.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I also had `return all(map(any, itertools.repeat(iter(it), num)))` but that didn't give much of a speedup.

Comment: How about, `gen = (item for item in it if item)` and then `return sum(itertools.islice(gen, num)) == num`

Comment: Thanks ! It is not the most obvious but seems to be the best regarding speed as I asked

Comment: @Chris_Rands That seems to be a lot slower, but a bit faster if you use `gen = filter(None, it)` instead.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Ok thanks, why is it slower? I guess the other option is using `list.index` a bit like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40351453/6260170 For the `n=2` case could be `try: lst.index(True,lst.index(True)+1)`

Comment: @StefanPochmann I prefer `filter(bool, it)` (more explicit and as fast) but the `sum` approach is even then a tiny bit slower. I think the problem is that `sum` really does a few arithmetic ops whereas `all` can just discard previous items.

Answer (score 4):

```
L = [True, False, False, True]
```

This does only the needed iterations:

```
def many(iterable, n):
    if n < 1:
        return True
    counter = 0
    for x in iterable:
        if x:
            counter += 1
            if counter == n:
                return True
    return False
```

Now:

```
>>> many(L, 2)
True
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Right, would avoid unneeded `if`. Updated, thanks.

Comment: I started thinking about something similar to this one. Though not the fastest one, it has the advantage to be very readable :)

Comment: That is a viable option. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum`:

```
sum(l) >= 2
# True
```

Comment: That's O(n) needlessly

Comment: @Chris_Rands `sum` is a built-in function, so I guess it should be faster than a for loop in python which can also be O(n) in worst cases.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `any` goes through the iterable until it finds a element that is `True`, and then stops.

Your solution scans all of the elements to see if there are at least 2.  Instead, it should stop scanning as soon as it finds a second `True` element.