# Fastest way to check whether a value exists more often than X in a list

Tags: python, arrays, count

I have a long list (300 000 elements) and I want to check that each element in that list exists more than 5 times. So the simplest code is

```
[x for x in x_list if x_list.count(x) > 5]
```

However, I do not need to count how often x appears in the list, I can stop the counting after reaching at least 5 elements? 
I also do not need to go through all elements in x_list, since there is a chance that I checked value x already earlier when going through the list.
Any idea how to get an optimal version for this code?
My output should be a list, with the same order if possible...

Comment: You could use a Counter object from the collections module. That would be linear. Your suggested code is quadratic.

Comment: @JohnColeman But the OP is suggesting `I can stop the counting after reaching at least 5 elements`, And `Counter` would still parse the whole list to get number of occurrences of each element.

Comment: You have to parse the whole list anyways.

Comment: @ZdaR You are right that counter wouldn't be optimal, but it is just a couple of lines and will be reasonably quick.

Comment: @JohnColeman Hmmm I agree, I whole list needs to be parsed anyways

Comment: Exactly what do you want returned? A true if all elements have a count of at least 5?

Comment: yes True would work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351219/efficiently-check-if-an-element-occurs-at-least-n-times-in-a-list

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the `Counter`-based solution:

```
from collections import Counter

items = [2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,3,4,4,1,2,4,3,1,4,3,4,1,2,1]
counts = Counter(items)
print(all(c >= 5 for c in counts.values())) #prints True
```

If I use

```
items = [random.randint(1,1000) for i in range(300000)]
```

The counter-based solution is still a fraction of a second.

Comment: Can you explain why the Counter function is faster than the count() function provided by the list itself?

Comment: @carl `items.count(x)` would scan over the whole list for each and every `x`, whereas `Counter()` builds up the counts in a single pass.

Comment: thanks Coleman you solution is nice and short, but I accepted the answer by neil since he claims his is faster... even though it seems to do the same thing?

Comment: Besides the algorithmic advantages of making a single pass and doing amortized O(1) lookups, a Counter has the advantage of a highly-optimized C-speed inner-loop that can't be beat by any other pure python solution.   This answer is about as fast as you can get without having some fore-knowledge of a particular element that occurs infrequently.

Answer (score 9):

Believe it or not, just doing a regular loop is much more efficient:

Data is generated via:

```
import random
N = 300000
arr = [random.random() for i in range(N)]
#and random ints are generated: arr = [random.randint(1,1000) for i in range(N)]
```

A regular loop computes in 0.22 seconds and if I use ints then it is .12 (very comparable to that of collections) (on a 2.4 Ghz processor).

```
di = {}
for item in arr:
    if item in di:
        di[item] += 1
    else:
        di[item] = 1
print (min(di.values()) > 5)
```

Your version greater than 30 seconds with or without integers.

```
[x for x in arr if arr.count(x) > 5]
```

And using collections takes about .33 seconds and .11 if I use integers.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(arr)
print(all(c >= 5 for c in counts.values()))
```

Finally, this takes greater than 30 seconds with or without integers:

```
count = [0]*(max(x_list)+1)
for x in x_list:
    count[x]+=1;
return [index for index, value in enumerate(count) if value >= 5]
```

Comment: I think you have a bug in your else branch, should be `di[item] = 1`. Another reason to prefer using the standard lib.

Comment: It probably does not matter whether it's `0.33` v `0.22` seconds... yet the `Counter` solution is: 1) much shorter 2) much easily verified correct

Comment: Don't you need to drop the "if item in di:" line from the example using di.get()?

Comment: Instead of the `if` branch for non-existent dict entries you can initialize `di` as `collections.defaultdict(0)` and simply add *and* update entries with `di[item] += 1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a more optimized way, you can use `numpy.unique()` method which is by far faster than python methods for large arrays like the one that you're dealing with:

```
import numpy as np
(np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)[1] > 5).all()
```

Also as a pythonic way you can use `collections.defaultdict()` like following:

```
In [56]: from collections import defaultdict

In [57]: def check_defaultdict(arr):                                   
             di = defaultdict(int)
             for item in arr:
                 di[item] += 1
             return (min(di.values()) > 5)
   ....:
```

Here is a benchmark with other methods:

```
In [39]: %timeit (np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)[1] > 5).all()
100 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop

In [58]: %timeit check_defaultdict(arr)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.1 ms per loop
"""
In [42]: def check(arr):
             di = {}
             for item in arr:
                 if item in di:
                    di[item] += 1
                 else:
                    di[item] = 1
             return (min(di.values()) > 5)
   ....:          
"""
In [43]: %timeit check(arr)
10 loops, best of 3: 56.6 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit all(c >= 5 for c in Counter(arr).values())
10 loops, best of 3: 89.5 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

To count all elements you could do something like this:

```
def atLeastFiveOfEach(x_list):
    count = [0]*(max(x_list)+1)
    for x in x_list:
        count[x]+=1;
    if min(count)<5:
        return False
    return True
```

Then you have list, count where count[i] is the number of occurrences of i in x_list.

If you want a list of all those elements, you can do like this:

```
def atLeastFiveOfEach(x_list):
    count = [0]*(max(x_list)+1)
    for x in x_list:
        count[x]+=1;
    return [index for index, value in enumerate(count) if value >= 5]
```

To explain a little bit why this is so much faster:

In your method, you pick the first element and goes through the whole list to see how many elements that equals that element it exists. Then you take the second element and traverse the whole list again. You're going through the whole list once FOR EACH element.

This method, on the other hand only goes through the list once. That's why it is much faster.

Comment: why is that faster than the solution I wrote above?

Comment: I haven't heard of ++ operator in Python, is it introduced in some latest version ?

Comment: What if the list doesn't consist of smallish integers?

Comment: sorry I require a list of objects back were each element appears at least 5 times... and I still don't understand why your example is any faster than mine? You are still counting all x?

Comment: Well, it just is faster. I tried it. It's also a little faster than Colemans suggestion. However, it can be slower if the items has a very high value. The complexity is O(n+k) where n is size of the list and k is the maximum value.

Comment: In the special case that the elements of the list are small integers, this is a fairly natural bucket-count and it will be quite fast for that case (so +1) but it does have the drawback of not being able to work with e.g. lists of strings or (as you point out) larger integers.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes you are right. I did however try it on a list where max was 3*10⁸ and it finished in less than 10s, so it's not that bad even on relatively high numbers.

Comment: Since you initialize `count`, you could try `count = dict.fromkeys(x_list, 0)`, and you'll only get the actual entries, not all the integers up to `max(x_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.islice`. It returns only selected items from an iterable.

```
from itertools import islice

def has_at_least_n(iterable, item, n=5):
    filter = (i for i in iterable if i == item)
    return next(islice(filter, n-1, None), False)
```

From Python documentation, here is what it has to say on `itertools.islice`

Make an iterator that returns selected elements from the iterable. If start is non-zero, then elements from the iterable are skipped until start is reached. Afterward, elements are returned consecutively unless step is set higher than one which results in items being skipped. If stop is None, then iteration continues until the iterator is exhausted, if at all; otherwise, it stops at the specified position. Unlike regular slicing, islice() does not support negative values for start, stop, or step. Can be used to extract related fields from data where the internal structure has been flattened (for example, a multi-line report may list a name field on every third line)

From Moses Koledoye's answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351219/efficiently-check-if-an-element-occurs-at-least-n-times-in-a-list/40498186#40498186)