# Is there a simple loop for rolling 6 dice until atleast 4 are the same number?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement

The question reads like this "Create a program that simulates the roll of a die. Have the program output the rolls of six dice repeatedly until at least four of the dice roll the same number."

I've come so far to where I just need the loop to make the dice continue rolling until they get the same as the first dice. I'm new to Python so I've tried reading about loop and I've tried some but it wouldn't work.

```
roll1 = random.choice(dice)    
print(roll1)    
roll2 = random.choice(dice)    
if roll2 == roll1:    
    print(roll2)
```

The outcome I want is that it rolls the first dice, then the second dice, and if it's the same it prints the second dice and continues to the third dice, but if it's different it will roll again until it's the same.

Comment: Since this question essentially boils down to "how check if an element occurs at least n times in a list" (once you get a list of six random digits between 1 to 6):

Possible duplicate of [Efficiently check if an element occurs at least n times in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351219/efficiently-check-if-an-element-occurs-at-least-n-times-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

This way'll be working. Let me know if anyone knows a better way.

I use function to break the all loops.

```
import random

def foo():
    while True:
        dice_list = random.choices(range(1, 7), k=6)
        dice_set = set(dice_list)

        if len(dice_set) > 3:
            continue

        for d in dice_set:
            if dice_list.count(d) > 3:
                return dice_list
```

Comment: `random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]*6, 6)` can simply be `random.choices(range(1, 7), k=6)`. Cleaner and faster

Answer (score 0):

I experimented some with loops and did this, it seems correct for me

```
import random

dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

same_dice = []

roll1 = random.choice(dice)
print("first dice is: ", roll1)
same_dice.append(roll1)

while True:
    roll2 = random.choice(dice)
    if roll2 in same_dice:
        print("two dice are", roll2)
        break
    else:
        random.choice(dice)
while True:
    roll3 = random.choice(dice)
    if roll3 in same_dice:
        print("three dice are", roll3)
        break
    else:
        random.choice(dice)
while True:
    roll4 = random.choice(dice)
    if roll4 in same_dice:
        print("four dice are", roll4)
        break
    else:
        random.choice(dice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @SaltyGaben and welcome to SO. You have stated the problem to be

> Create a program that simulates the roll of a die. Have the program output the rolls of six dice repeatedly until at least four of the dice roll the same number.

You may think of this as repeatedly rolling 6 dice simultaneously until at least 4 of them roll the same number.

I have tested the following code that uses a single `while` loop. Note that `dice_output[i]` is the roll of `i`th die.

```
import random

output_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0]    # A list to keep track of occurrences of each number between 1 to 6
dice_output = []

while True:
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice_output.append(roll)
    output_count[roll - 1] += 1
    l = len(dice_output)

    if (l == 6) and (4 in output_count):
        print("Dice :", dice_output)
        print("Count:", output_count)
        break

    if l == 6:
        print("Dice :", dice_output)
        output_count = [0,0,0,0,0,0]    # Resetting the counts
        dice_output = []                # Resetting the dice_output
```

Here is one of the outputs I got:

```
Output:
Dice : [3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 5]
Dice : [5, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4]
Dice : [6, 6, 3, 1, 1, 5]
Dice : [3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 3]
Dice : [3, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6]
Dice : [1, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3]
Dice : [4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6]
Dice : [5, 5, 6, 6, 3, 4]
Dice : [2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6]
Dice : [2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1]
Dice : [6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1]
Dice : [5, 5, 6, 6, 4, 2]
Dice : [5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2]
Dice : [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5]
Count: [4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a nice solution but sometimes I got some weird results where it said "Dice : [5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5]" but then this "Count: [0, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0]" at the end, but sometimes it looked like your result.

Comment: @SaltyGaben The result you obtained is not actually weird. The `output_count` list keeps track of occurrences of each number from 1 to 6. So, `output_count[0]` stores how many times 1 was rolled when 6 dice were rolled, `output_count[1]` stores how many times 2 was rolled when 6 dice were rolled, and so on. Sorry if I made it a bit confusing, but hope this helps clarify your doubt.